# ComboBox in Win32Api C++

Tags: c++, combobox

i'm new in programming API with C++. I have a problem with create a ComboBox when adding new values in it. This is my code:

```
void inline createName(HWND hwnd) {
    CreateWindow(TEXT("STATIC"), TEXT("Name"),
        WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD,
        10, 10, 100, 20,
        hwnd, NULL, NULL, NULL
      );
HWND comboBox = CreateWindow(TEXT("COMBOBOX"), NULL,
    CBS_DROPDOWN | WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE,
    120, 10, 200, 20,
    hwnd, NULL, NULL, NULL
    );
TCHAR Names[2][50] =
{
    TEXT("FIRST VALUE"), TEXT("SECOND VALUE")
};

for (int index = 0; index < 2; index++) {

    //Add string to combobox
    SendMessage(comboBox, (UINT)CB_ADDSTRING, (WPARAM)0, (LPARAM)Names[index]);
}
SendMessage(comboBox, CB_SETCURSEL, (WPARAM)0, (LPARAM)0);
```

}
When i run this code, it only show the value I put in CB_SETCURSEL but I can't select other values. Which means that the dropdown button doesn't work.
I get that code from here: 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh298364(v=vs.85).aspx

Thanks in advance!

EDIT: This is my WinProc function, I only finished the GUI part.

```
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hwnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) {

switch (msg) {
case WM_CREATE:
    createMenuBar(hwnd);
    createName(hwnd);
    createSex(hwnd);
    createLanguage(hwnd);
    createAddress(hwnd);
    createButton(hwnd);
    break;
case WM_CLOSE:
    DestroyWindow(hwnd);
    break;
case WM_DESTROY:
    PostQuitMessage(0);
    break;
default:
    return DefWindowProc(hwnd, msg, wParam, lParam);
}
return 0;
```

}

Comment: Please show us your `WndProc` function. You aren't putting any values when sending the `CB_SETCURSEL` message, you are merely selecting a string in a list of combobox items. This functions as expected, your problem is elsewhere.

Comment: Edited. Yeah, the combobox only show the string i set with CB_SETCURSEL. When i clicked on the arrow, it supposed to drop a list with "SECOND VALUE" string.

Comment: The above code produces the [desired behaviour](http://i.imgur.com/fUMtZZ1.png). The problem is elsewhere.

Comment: I figured it out! You have to set the height of combo box longer than the list, otherwise the partitions won't be shown :)))

Comment: Anyways, better use dialog box templates. It will be much more easier

Answer (score 1):

This is a really common problem for new users of comboboxes.  Comboboxes are weird in that the height must include the height of the drop-down list, not just the edit control at the top.

I'm glad to see in the comments that you've figured this out.  I'm adding this so future readers have a better chance of spotting the answer.